# Replace element with text with javascript (no jquery)

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm trying to create a link which has a dynamic value in it

```
http://my.link/index.php?action=huh&id=X
```

The X is what i want to replace dynamically with javascript variable.
I don't want to use jquery for it.

AND, i **do not want to replace the whole url(href)** because some part of URL needs to parsed by the template engine.
I think it'd be better if i inserted an element in place of X and replaced it with JS

Comment: Do your anchors with a dynamic href have a class? Is this not contained in an anchor? Yes, it can be done in Javascript but we need more info on your implementation.

Comment: yes. It does have a class. I edited my question to make it easier to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only replace id

```
var elLink = document.getElementById("link");
elLink.href = elLink.href.replace(/id=(.*)/, function(){return "id=2"});
```

if id=X is constant

```
elLink.href = elLink.href.replace("id=X", "id=2");
```

Comment: That worked like charm. but it removes the rest of my URL.
This is my full URL: 
`http://my.link/index.php?action=huh&id=X&k={$template_engine_stuff}`
..... after applying your code, the result is :
`http://my.link/index.php?action=huh&id=2`

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: damn. I feel like an idiot. It works perfectly now
You sir, are my hero

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

document.getElementById("YourAnchorId").href= document.getElementById("YourAnchorId").href + id;

or

document.getElementById("YourAnchorId").href= document.getElementById("YourAnchorId").href +"?id" + id;

And that id variable get it from a textbox or however you need it.

And whats its the reason for not using jquery?

Comment: well, i do not want to replace the whole href because (as i stated in my post), some part of the url needs to by parsed by the template engine
And i don't want to use jquery because 1. it conflicts with my prototype 2. i don't want to add unnecessary 89KB

Comment: I'd try that. But i already got a working solution. thanks for giving your time tho